# How to understand header of H264

Tags: h.264

My NAL unit looks like this:

00 00 00 01 67 42 00 1F E6 20 0A 00 B6 60 22 00 00 03 00 02 00 00 03 00 79 C0 00 00 10 FD D0 00 00 40 16 43 F4 A4 18 00 00 03 02 1D 97 00 00 1A B3 F1 FA 52 05 00 00 00 01 68

How can I understand what is the data in RBSP? Like payload size and what parts of the data signifies it.

Comment: I found a good explanation of the format in this website: [link](http://gentlelogic.blogspot.nl/2011/11/exploring-h264-part-2-h264-bitstream.html). I don't know if it actually answer your questions but I think it could help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the H264 format the byte stream is organised into many NAL unit. In order to understand where a NAL unit starts a three-byte or four-byte start code, 0x000001 or 0x00000001, is placed at the beginning of each NAL unit.

[image]
There is the possibility that this sequence is present also in the raw data, in this case an **emulation prevention byte** 0x03 is used to transform the sequences 0x000000, 0x000001, 0x000002 and 0x000003 into 0x00000300, 0x00000301, 0x00000302 and 0x00000303 respectively.

In each NAL unit the header occupies just the first byte of its sequence, the rest of the byte represents the actual payload.

[image: image2]

The header contains information about the type of data contained in the payload, and it can divided in three parts.

The header 0x67 ( which is the header in your NAL unit ) for example corresponds to the binary sequence *0110 0111*. The first bit of this sequence ( which is a *0* ) is the **forbidden zero** and is used to verify if errors where encountered during the transmission of the packet.

The following 2 bits ( the *11* ) are called **nal_ref_idc** and they indicates if NAL unit is a reference field, frame or picture.

The remaining 5 bits specify the **nal_unit_type**. It specifies the type of RBSP data structure contained in the NAL unit. For a more detailed explanation of the NAL unit header you can refer to table 7.1 found in [here](http://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/) or to the [official RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#page-13)

Comment: How can I know from the header that how much data will follow the header. That is how much is the size of the payload?

Comment: There is no information in the header regarding the size of the payload, you get the size of each NAL unit by looking at the three-byte or four-byte start code.

Comment: what is the information in the 3 bytes or 4 bytes as you said we can get the information of size

Comment: You can tell that a NAL unit starts when you find the 0x000001 or 0x00000001 bytes. After those bytes you have the header of one byte, then the payload. The payload is over when the next NAL unit starts, again with 0x000001 or 0x00000001 bytes. Look at the first image in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input

Comment: If you have a h264 file contains many frames, is there a way to know where the frame boundaries are? i.e. not just the NAL bounderies.

Comment: Why replace 0x000002? You only need to replace 0x000001 with 0x00000301 and then original 0x000003s with 0x00000303 so they dont get confused with the emulation byte replacement